# How to convert superclass to subclass in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, superclass

As the title described below , A superclass ,the name is ZpIOObject

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, ZpIOObjectType) {
      ZpIOObjectType_NONE = 0 , // is no exist file or no judgment object type
      ZpIOObjectType_File ,     // it's a file object
      ZpIOObjectType_Document   // it's a document object
};
@interface ZpIOObject:NSObject
      @property (nonatomic , assign ) ZpIOObjectType fileType ; 
      @property (nonatomic , strong ) NSString *absolutePathString ;

      /**create an object or subobject*/
      +(instancetype) ioObjectWithAbsolutePathString:(NSString *)absolutePathString ;
@end
```

A subclass , the name is ZpIOFileObject

```
@interface ZpIOFileObject : ZpIOObject
      - (void)fileDataWithAsynchronize:(void(^)(NSData *fileData))result ;
@end
```

Another subclass , the name is ZpIODocumentObject

```
@interface ZpIODocumentObject : ZpIOObject
      @property (nonatomic , strong , readonly) NSArray<ZpIOObject*> *subIOObjects ;
@end

@implementation ZpIODocumentObject
@synthesize subIOObjects = _subIOObjects ;

- (NSArray<ZpIOObject *>*)subIOObjects
{
    if( nil == self.absolutePathString || YES == [[self.absolutePathString trim] isEqualToString:emptyString] ){
        return nil ;
    }
    if( nil != self.error ){
        return nil ;
    }
    // 进行IO操作，获取最新的文件当前层级的子文件、子文件夹，一定是最新数据，但对IO开销大
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;
    NSError *error ;
    NSArray<NSString*>* subDirsNameArr = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.absolutePathString error:&error] ;
    if( nil == subDirsNameArr || 0 == [subDirsNameArr count] ){
        return nil ;
    }
    for( NSString *subFilePathString in subDirsNameArr ){
        NSMutableString *subFileAbsolutePathString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:subFilePathString] ;
        [subFileAbsolutePathString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",subFilePathString]] ;
        ZpIOObject * ioobject = [ZpIOObject ioObjectWithAbsolutePathString:subFileAbsolutePathString] ;
        switch ( ioobject.fileType ) {
            case ZpIOObjectType_File:{
            ; // How to convert ZpIOObject to ZpIOFileObject ??????
            }
            case ZpIOObjectType_Document:{
            ; // How to convert ZpIOObject to ZpIODocumentObject ??????
            }
            break;
        default:{/*do nothing*/}break ;
        }
    }
    return nil ;
}
@end
```

You can see this code :

```
        switch ( ioobject.fileType ) {
            case ZpIOObjectType_File:{
            ; // How to convert ZpIOObject to ZpIOFileObject ??????
            }
            case ZpIOObjectType_Document:{
            ; // How to convert ZpIOObject to ZpIODocumentObject ??????
            }
            break;
        default:{/*do nothing*/}break ;
        }
```

I want to convert ZpIOObject to ZpIOFileObject/ZpIODocumentObject .

I think you will think is so easy :
create ZpIOFileObject/ZpIODocumentObject and assignment .
for example:

```
        ZpIOFileObject *fileObject = [[ZpIOFileObject alloc] init] ;
        fileObject.property = ioobject.property
... do something ...
```

No ! I don't want this .

I want a superclass convert to subclass , why ?
In my opinion , ioObject is a existing object , create(alloc) a new object(for example [[ZpIOFileObject alloc] init])  is Waste memory resources !

I can't bear to waste memory resources ！

So ， My question is :

If superclass is an existing object , How to convert superclass' object to subclass' object ?

Comment: Are you trying to "cast" the super class to the subclass? (down casting?) If so, just do `ZpIOFileObject *fileObject = (ZPIOFileObject *)ZpIOObject;`

Comment: thank you your answer ,  yes , you  can understand for down casting 。 but the code   ZpIOFileObject *fileObject = (ZPIOFileObject *)ZpIOObject; is wrong ! because the ZpIOObject have two subobject

Comment: What? That's what your case statement is for. You already know what type it is. You should be able to cast to the right type.

Comment: your can see : ZpIODocumentObject.m , you can find a getter method : subIOObjects 。 My code get an object : ZpIOObject* ioobject in ' for ' code block . but the ioobject's class is ZpIOObject , it's not ZPIOFileObject . so ZpIOFileObject *fileObject = (ZPIOFileObject *)ZpIOObject; is wrong

Comment: You write you “can't bear to waste memory” yet you seem to be doing exactly that by storing the type twice. Either use subclasses to store the type or use the `ZpIOObjectType fileType` property. Use whichever way is more appropriate to your use case. It seems to me subclasses are the way to go because your methods for the various types differ. So if you initialize the object with the correct type to begin with you don’t ever have to re-init anything.

Comment: To answer your question: You could use `class_getInstanceMethod` to call your subclass methods on instances of another class (including the superclass), thus avoiding initializing a new instance and then copying the properties. But why make it messy when there’s already a clean way?

Answer (score 1):

Tested for a long time, I am sure, can't do that 。

subclass' object can convert to superclass' object , but superclass' object cannot convert to subclass' object .

```
for example :

A inheritance ASuper

A *a = [[A alloc] init] ;
ASuper * aSuper = a ; // right 
A *aAnother = (A *) aSuper ; // right 

ASuper * aSuperAnother = [[ASpuer alloc]init] ;
A *a_other = aSuperAnother ; // Error !
```